# WSAPI - Can you get the User Profile Image?

Tags: rally

It looks like the User object contains most of the information found on the user detail page within Rally (with the rest seeming to be on UserProfile). - However in Rally I can see the users "Profile Image", but I don't see a way of querying this using the API.

Is there a way to query the user profile image for each user (in particular for all users where the profile image has not been set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) object model neither User nor UserProfile object has an attribute that points to the profile image.

You may however access it via a URL that follows this syntax:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/profile/viewThumbnailImage.sp?tSize=150&uid=12345
```

Where 12345 is the OID of the user.
This is not officially supported.This URL endpoint may change without notice.

Comment: Just be sure to request this URL with a valid cookie from `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/j_spring_security_check` using `j_username` and `j_password`.